# Polygon casting - Removing from mold by rotation

Tags: algorithms, reductions, computational-geometry

The following question appears in Section 4.9 of "Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications" By Mark de Berg, Marc van Kreveld, Mark Overmars, and Otfried Schwarzkopf:

> Show that the problem of finding a center of rotation that allows us
>   to remove $P$ with a single rotation from its mold can be reduced to the
>   problem of finding a point in the common intersection of a set of
>   half-planes.

$P$ here is a simple polygon with a given orientation, cast in a mold - 
[image: Rotation from mold]

Whether $P$ can be removed with a translation can be reduced to whether 
a common intersection of a set of half-planes is unbounded: Each edge of $P$, continued to a line, defines the half plane touching the outer side of the edge. The intersection of these half-planes is unbounded in a direction $\vec{v}$ if and only if translating $P$ by $\vec{v}$ does not cause any edge to push against the mold.

How can this reduction be modified to solve the case of removing $P$ with a rotation around a point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the marked edge of the following object (light gray) in its mold (dark gray) - 
[image: edge of object in mold]

Where must $p$ be such that an arbitrary points on the edge will not be pushed against the mold? This figure shows the direction a point on the edge will be moving in when rotated around a point $p$ - 
[image: pivot rotation direction]

Notice that the point will be moving perpendicular to the line connecting it with $p$. Now recall that in order not to push on the mold, the points of the edge must move in the direction of the inner half-plane defined by the edge. This means that the possible locations for $p$ lie on a half-plane perpendicular to the edge. Here's the half-plane (in green) corresponding to an inner point of the edge - 
[image]

The half-plane corresponding to the upper vertex of the edge, in this case, is contained in all of the half-planes for inner points, and so a rotation around any point in it moves the entire edge such that it does not push on the mold.

Whether $P$ can be removed with a rotation around $p$, is thus equivalent to whether $p$ is in the common intersection of the half-planes defined by $P$'s edges.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Thank  you for the detailed answer and edit to the question!  I hope you'll stick around and continue to contribute.